# how to get out of editText after typing the text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

i have prepared a entry screen for my program and where i have put an edittext and also ImageViews.Now the problem is that m able to type the text inside the edittext through the virtual keyboard but the problem is that after i m done with my text then i m not able to come out of the edittext,the cursor remains at the edittext box only.
i have a imageView below to be clicked to proceed with the form but it is nt clickable at that momen..please help!!!

my code is

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/begin_"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
         android:src="@drawable/begin" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/enter_name" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/roof"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/roof" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
         android:ems="8"
         android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
         android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

my main java class

```
package game.pack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Begin extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            setContentView(R.layout.entry);

        ImageView begin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.begin_);
        begin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.begin_:
            setContentView(new SushiMain(this));
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

my android manifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="game.pack"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".FrontScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Begin"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
          <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="begingame" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Sushitap"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="gameover" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [View.OnKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) for EditText to remove Focus from EditText when ENTER KEY PRESSED after typing in EditText :

```
ditText.setOnKeyListener(onSoftKeyboardDonePress);

    private View.OnKeyListener onSoftKeyboardDonePress=new View.OnKeyListener() 
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                 // code to hide the soft keyboard
                 EditTexst.clearFocus();
                 EditTexst.requestFocus(EditText.FOCUS_DOWN);            
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: @Sudy91 : edit your question with latest code and make your question more clear means what exactly you want?

Comment: i was goin to put my emulator screen shot but due to lack of reputation m not able to
the above code is my final edit if i could show you the emulator then it could be even more clear!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
editTextId.clearFocus();
editTextId.requestFocus(EditText.FOCUS_DOWN); // assuming that you want to move the focus to the next View Element. If you want it to go to the previous View, use FOCUS_UP
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: no not working yet and i do not have an method for calling the virtual keyboard it just gets called when i click on the edittext!!!
so wher do i put the above code???

Comment: Define a KeyListener on the EditText and as soon as the user presses ENTER, you execute this code to remove the focus.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your edittext in your xml to your code. In your oncreate method add

```
EditText edittext= (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting this in layout file for edittext?

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app requires an edit text and an image view next to it..then here's the code u can use.
 In layout.xml u can add this code for edittext with image

```
<LinearLayout        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white2" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_search"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_20"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search_brdNm" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in your java class you can have this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_asset);

        mEt_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_search);

    mEt_search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str_searchTxt = mEt_search.getText().toString().trim();
                String str_channelNm = AppConfigurationUtils.getChannelName();
                if (str_searchTxt.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getResources().getString(R.string.ENTER_MANDATORY),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can add this to your `ImageView`s in layout file `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`.Because focus is gained only if something is focusable on touch so you have to make your images focusable on touch.

Answer (score 0):

HEY guys my problem is solved!!!
actually i was moving from some other view to this view and in the first view i was calling the present class activity by its layout Id so in this case the imageview was not behaving as a normal button but as just a view

so in the first view i used an intent to call the class of the activity which i hav posted above and this successfully completed my task!!!

Thank you everyone for your time and efforts...much appreciated!!!!

THANK YOU!!!